# Radio Button not working in webkit browsers

Tags: css, google-chrome, safari

the problem is simple to explain, i have done a form, but the radio buttons are not showing in safari, and in chrome they are showing but they're not clickable.Is it a problem of css? The radio buttons are just as normal as they should:

```
<input type="radio" name="message" value="x" checked> Option
```

What am I doing wrong?
Agnese

Comment: provide more code, this is literally nothing to go on

Comment: It's working fine for me in chrome? http://jsfiddle.net/fRGMe/ as Novocaine said provide more code as there is most likely something else going on.

Answer (score 0):

Check if there are any elements overlapping, maybe you used floating without a clearfix which means your browser does not get the height of your form?

Answer (score -2):

`<input type="radio" name="message" value="x" checked="true"> Option`

Try this. The checked needs to be set and not left empty.

Refer to the image below to see it in action. Tested on W3Shools itself.
[image]

Comment: :O seriously? `Option </input>`

Comment: That's *not* how input elements should be written

Comment: If you look at what he provided, You will find that he used 'Option'. I simply gave him a working version of what he had, you low life.

Comment: what you wrote is invalid html. Give it a try yourself: http://validator.w3.org/check

Comment: The only reason it fails is because there isnt a doc type specified. Paste it in a text file, save it as html, open with a browser and see it work. I HAVE CHECKED IT.

Comment: It is a radio type and so </input> is not needed, this is why it is not valid. http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_radio

Comment: So because its not needed, makes it wrong? Did it work or not?

Comment: Not saying its "wrong" just backing up what Novocaine said about it not being valid ;)

Comment: I can understand that, But marking my answer as negative when it does in fact work is wrong.

Comment: I downvoted not just because it is invalid html, but the code you provided does not actually differ in output compared to the OP's code. It is therefore not a useful answer. A correct answer would be complete luck at this stage considering how little code the OP has provided.